# How to create a heatmap of two-letter combos in a list of words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been given a list of 40000 or so 8 letter words and what to analyse the frequency of two letter combos within these words. Similar to [this](http://mechanicalscribe.com/notes/most-common-two-letter-combinations/).

I have been using the COUNTIF function in a very ugly and inefficent way and believe there must be a better way to accomplish this task.

For example below is what I would use for the ED frequency where B2:B40162 containts the list of words.

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B40162, "??????ed")+COUNTIF(B2:B40162, "?????ed?")+COUNTIF(B2:B40162, "????ed??")+COUNTIF(B2:B40162, "???ed???")+COUNTIF(B2:B40162, "??ed????")+COUNTIF(B2:B40162, "?ed?????")+COUNTIF(B2:B40162, "ed??????")
```

I am certain there is not only a better method, but also, a method that allows me to select cells instead of manually putting in the letter combonations 26² times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Grid starts in C1(as your list is in B)

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"*" & D$1 & $C2 & "*")
```

Put that in D2 and copy over and down.

The above will only count each match once per cell.  For Example `EDITED` would only be counted once for `ED`  if that does not work then you will need to do the addition of many COUNTIF()s using the model you started with.

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B, "??????" & D$1 & $C2 )+COUNTIF($B:$B, "?????" & D$1 & $C2 & "?")+COUNTIF($B:$B, "????" & D$1 & $C2 & "??")+COUNTIF($B:$B, "???" & D$1 & $C2 & "???")+COUNTIF($B:$B, "??" & D$1 & $C2 & "????")+COUNTIF($B:$B, "?" & D$1 & $C2 & "?????")+COUNTIF($B:$B, D$1 & $C2 & "??????")
```

Comment: Can condense second formula like so (if desired): `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($B:$B,REPT("?",6-(ROW($1:$7)-1))&D$1&$C2&REPT("?",ROW($1:$7)-1)))`